# Can't find Dashcode after installing Xcode 4 on brand new MacBook

Tags: xcode, dashcode

I have a brand new MacBook (air if it matters). I have installed Xcode 4 but I can't find Dashcode even using finder. What should I do ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can download Dashcode using the More Application Tools by choosing the xCode Menu -> Open Developer Tools -> More Developer Tools.

There's more information and screenshots in the [Developer Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html).

Comment: Direct link: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-